# Automating clay/brick production

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I'm trying to automate the production of bricks in Minecraft Agrarian Skies.

I can produce clay *blocks* no problem (wooden barrel + water via fluiduct + dust via ME export bus), and obviously I can produce bricks from clay balls (redstone furnace + clay ball via ME interface).

What I'm struggling with is automating the production of clay balls from blocks.

Putting the blocks in the pulverizer doesn't seem to work, and there doesn't seem to be either a way to make bricks from clay blocks or another easy way to make clay balls themselves.

The best solution I've come up with is to spawn the clay block into the world (via e.g. an autonomous activator) and smash it (with e.g. a terrain smasher).

Is there an easier way to automate the production of clay balls without putting clay blocks into the world?

Comment: Aren't clay balls produced sometimes when sifting one of the siftables? Haven't played AS in a while but I thought I remembered something like that.

Comment: What other mods are you using?  Is it just Agrarian Skies?

Comment: Just agrarian skies. It doesn't come from the sieve afaik.

Comment: just a thought but 4 clay balls=1 clay block. So unless you have a fortune enchanted shovel, you will get the amount required to make the block.  But past making it as a block with the balls is something im unaware of being done past command block, since its occurs in ponds and rivers.

Comment: @IainGalloway Agrarian Skies is a Feed The Beast pack. Why did you remove the tag?

Comment: Agrarian Skies is a 3rd party pack which happens to also be available through the Feed the Beast launcher. More importantly, FtB includes a bunch of machinery that isn't in AS (e.g. IndustrialCraft) and vice-versa.

Comment: You mentioned that you have AE. Formation plane -> Annihilation plane works well. In addition, if you go into NEI, look up clay, and hit `r` (shows recipe by default), then you'll see how <things> are made into clay balls. There's probably at least one machine that can pulverize the clay blocks accordingly.

Comment: Aw... Annihilation Plane would be perfect, but it's not in AE1 :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that a Terrain Smasher-Autonomous Activator setup is your only option here. Agrarian Skies doesn't have quite as many mods as Monster, so there simply aren't as many options for processing.

The good thing is that clay breaks quite quickly so processing it through the terrain smasher shouldn't be particularly slow. Also, the first stage of filling the containers and waiting for the dust to become clay takes about as long as to break clay with your hands, so there should be no waiting on the Terrain Smasher setup.